# Is it possible to retrieve bundle data More than once form already started activity

Tags: android

When I run my application I am going  From Class A------->Class B, Class B-->Class C,
Class C--->Class D.

I need to use Class A Bundle values in Class D. So what should I do to get the value & can you send some sample code?

Android Developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the data and variables from application to application you should consider using an Application object.  See this question and answer [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Java ( parcelable ) class P which contain all fields you want to use in Class D.
There are two ways
1. Save the object( of P ) in file and later read saved file in class D.
2. or Pass the object form one Activity to other Activity ( assuming A,B,C,D are Activity ).